# Most performant SQL solution for landing page-led return of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, offset

I am looking for the fastest method to return results from 1 table, based on criteria listed in another table.

We have a number of landing pages on our website. Each has a record in our **Landing** table in an SQL 2016 database, thus:

**ID** int (primary key + identity)

**Name** varchar(30)

**Criteria_Type** varchar(30)

**Criteria_Colour** varchar(10)

Each landing page record describes criteria of the products to be displayed. Additionally, the user on the website can override some criteria such as colour. Also, the criteria in Landing may be null because we might want all Widget product types irrespective of colour.

At present, the fastest way I can return results is by a stored procedure, thus:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GET_LANDING_RESULTS

   @LPID int,
   @PageNumber int,
   @Override_Colour varchar(10)       

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Criteria_Type varchar(30)
DECLARE @Criteria_Colour varchar(10)

/* read criteria from landing table */

SELECT
@Criteria_Type=Criteria_Type,
@Criteria_Colour=Criteria_Colour
FROM dbo.Landing
WHERE ID = @ID

IF @Override_Colour is not null
    @Criteria_Colour = @Override_Colour

/* get results */

SELECT
Count(ID) OVER() As TotalProducts,
ItemID,
Name,
ProductType,
Colour
Price
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE
(ProductType = @Criteria_Type OR @Criteria_Type is null) AND
(Colour = @Criteria_Colour OR @Criteria_Colour is null)
OFFSET @PageNumber ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

END
```

The web page passes through the ID number, page number and any colour override information and the procedure returns the products.

Is there a better way, perhaps with joins? There are many different criteria that can be applied - I have cut down this example.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that selecting the "next 10 rows" is pointless unless you have specified the `ORDER BY` in the query, since a query without that clause is [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm). It may be worth reading https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/ (credit to SeanLange for that link).

Comment: I missed out the ORDER BY, but it's there in the real procedure

Comment: Your question is lacking, and the over all logic is off. Please give us all the code. Here you only have a small bit of the query, we can give better answers if we had the DDL and some sample data. Your question is illogical because you're asking the fastest way to return a record set and then limiting SQL from giving you the full record set. what does offset / fetch next do for you? are you passing the result set to an application / web page and then wait for input from an end user? Why not return the full set, cache it and then have the webpage pull from the cache? More info please

Comment: This approach is standard from the query stand point, offset / fetch next is not typical, but the underlying question I have to ask is, Why are you looking for performance gains from SQL? I doubt you are waiting on SQL to return records, if you are, I would look at indexing and maybe parameter sniffing, again need full disclose of code. It seems your question should include how can I metric performance of this query, to compare it to other query plans ... I know this way off base, but is it possible the issue isn't performance of SQL and dare I say .... the app / web code? /gasp

Comment: I just wanted to know the best practice for this kind of query. One doesn't know what one doesn't know, so others could perhaps enlighten should I be using an unsuitable method. I am not particularly looking to fix a problem, but there may have been major gains....